# Finding number of arrays such that first and last elements are same with unequal adjacent elements.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

The first and last elements of the array are the same.
The size of the array is `n` and the array element can have values in [1, `m`].
How to find the number of such arrays with the condition that adjacent elements are unequal?

Feels like it can be solved using the inclusion-exclusion principle, But I'm not able to formulate it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Note that there is a simple recursion.  First count the strings that pass the adjacency test (but ignore the first and last character test), call these $A_n$.  Then $A_n=B_n+C_n$ where $B_n$ also passes your character test and $C_n$ fails your character test.  But $C_n=B_{n+1}$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !!