# Count the number of sequences possible which have no adjacent element?

Tags: combinatorics

Length of the sequence = $N$

Each element of the sequence can be in the range $[1,M]$

$A[1]=1$

$A[N]=1$

Find the number of ways to assign values to remaining elements such that , $A[i]!=A[i+1]$, for any $'i'$

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It has come up recently.

Comment: My friend send me the screenshot of this problem . It was asked in Hackerearth intern test . He was not able to solve it . I want to know the solution to improve my combinatorics knowledge. @lulu

Comment: As the test appears to have ended, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954875/finding-number-of-arrays-such-that-first-and-last-elements-are-same-with-unequal?noredirect=1#comment8157531_3954875).  It's slightly different as the common first/last character is not specified in that one.  But the same hint applies.

Comment: @lulu I found the complete formula by myself, should I post it as an answer ?

Comment: Sure, why not? $\quad$

Answer (score 0):

Just an attempt. I might be wrong.

$A[1] = 1 = A[N]$ is fixed.

Each of the odd positions can be filled in  $M$ ways. The number of odd positions $k$ can be given by the following formula $k = N/2-2$ if $N$ is even and $k=(N+1)/2 - 2$ if $n$ is odd. So, now we have filled these odd positions in $M^k$ ways.

Now each of these intermediate positions can be filled two ways as follows:

1. If the previous odd position $\alpha-1$ has the same value as the current odd position $\alpha+1$, then the postion $\alpha$ can be filled in $M-1$ ways, i.e., if $A[\alpha-1] = A[\alpha+1]$, then $A[\alpha]$ can be filled in $M-1$ ways. If $A[\alpha-1] != A[\alpha+1]$, then $A[\alpha]$ can be filled in $M-2$ ways.
2. Assuming $A[\alpha-1]$ is fixed, $A[\alpha-1] != A[\alpha+1]$ can occur in $M-1$ ways and $A[\alpha-1] = A[\alpha+1]$ can occur in exactly $1$ way.

Combining the above two arguments, each even space can now be filled in
$$ (M-1).(M-2) + 1.(M-1) = (M-1)^2$$
ways. The total number of solutions should thus be something of the form
$$ M^k(M-1)^{2(N-k-2)}.$$